# In R metafor::escalc, why does SMD1 uses "sd2i" for standardization, but SMCR uses "sd1i"?

Tags: metafor, meta-analysis

In metafor::escalc why are the sd arguments inconsistent between `SMD1 and SMCR?`  Both use a single standard deviation for normalization, but `SMD1` uses `“sd2i” and SMCR uses “sd1i”`.

`MD (mean difference)` is consistently defined as `m1i - m2i`, implying that `“1”` is the treatment group and `“2”` is the control group or the pretest score (in the case of SMCR when there is no control group).

For `SMD1` the SD used for standardization is `sd2i`, which would naturally correspond to the `SD` of the control group.

But in `SMCR`, the `SD` that is used for standardization is sd1i (not `sd2i`).  The escalc documentation indicates this should be the pretest SD: “`sd1i` (`Becker, 1988; Morris, 2000`), which is usually the pre-test standard deviation...”.

But if the `MD is m1i - m2i`, then m1i would appear to be the mean of the post-test and sd1i would appear to be the SD of the post-test, not the SD of the pre-test.

Why the inconsistency?  It would make more sense for `sd2i` to be the argument used for the `SD` in `SMCR` just as it is in `SMD1`.  Am I missing something?

I've searched the escalc documentation and various web sites including stackoverflow but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For `SMCR`, if you think of 1 as the first measurement occasion (e.g., pre-treatment) and 2 as the second measurement occasion (e.g., post-treatment), then we *typically* want to standardize based on the SD of the first measurement. On the other hand, for `SMD1`, we might think of 1 as the treatment group and 2 as the control group and then we *typically* want to standardize based on the SD of the control group. But these are not hard rules, just ways these measures are introduced/described. For `SMCR`, one can use `m1i` to specify the post-treatment means and `m2i` for the pre-treatment means and you are free to specify either one of the corresponding SDs for `sd1i`. Similarly, for `SMD1`, you are free to use `m1i` and `m2i` for the means of either group and use either SD for `sd2i`. Nothing changes about the statistical properties of these measures.